# Efficient Way to Create a Pivot Table in XSL/Datatables?

Tags: xml, xslt, datatables

I'm trying to create a pivot table where companies are listed on the `thead` and the account/description is the first two `td` and for each company the sum of actuals by account is in the `td` below it. Like this:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Acct | Acct_desc | Comp1     | Comp2     | Comp3    | . . .
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 1220 | wage_sals | 10,500.00 | 55,201.00 | 1,378.00 | . . .
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 1230 | wage_hour | 12,987.50 | 48,988.00 | 7,427.00 | . . .
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 . . .
```

However my report is generating very slowly. I suspect that this is because I am doing n*n operations whereas maybe there is a way I could reduce that. Please see below:

DATA: (company, acct and acct desc are not unique) (we also have the freedom to change the structure of this if need be)

```
<G_1>
  <COMPANY>Comp1</COMPANY>
  <CAT_CODE>1 REVENUE</CAT_CODE>
  <ACCT_3>1220</ACCT_3>
  <ACCT3_DESC>wage_sals</ACCT3_DESC>
  <ACTUAL>1000</ACTUAL>
</G_1>
 . . .
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="comps"   select="G_1/COMPANY[not(.=preceding::*)]" as="element()"/>
<xsl:variable name="rev"     select="G_1[CAT_CODE='1 REVENUE']" as="element()"/>
     <tbody>
       <!-- Revenue -->
       <xsl:for-each-group select="$rev" group-by="concat(string(ACCT_3), '|', ACCT3_DESC)">
         <xsl:variable name="account" select="substring-before(current-grouping-key(), '|')"/>
         <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current-grouping-key(), '|')"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(current-grouping-key(), '|')"/></td>
           <xsl:for-each select="$comps">
             <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="format-number(-sum(current-group()[COMPANY=current()]/ACTUAL), '#,###.00')"/>
             </td>
           </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
```

This example seems rather simple and like it'd be fast, but we are doing this for hundreds of companies and hundreds of accounts, so at scale it becomes very slow.

Comment: Could you share some more rows/data in XML to understand how the structure expands for bigger data

Comment: Comparing on `preceding::*` always seems expensive. You haven't shown any broader context to allow us to tell whether `distinct-values(G_1/COMPANY)` or grouping `G_1` on `COMPANY` can be more efficient to identify unique company (names).

Comment: It also seems that perhaps doing a nested grouping `<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="COMPANY"><td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(-sum(current-group()/ACTUAL), '#,###.00')"/></td></xsl:for-each-group>` suffices.

Comment: Could you apply the suggestions in the comments? Either summarize any solution you have in an answer of your own or let us know what is still missing.